# Where does the claim for the punsishment for wasting food and water come from?

Tags: source-identification

My cousin told me that his Islamic teacher said that for every time you waste food/drink, one day you won't get any food/drink.

Where does this come from?

Comment: quran 7:31, "sahih international" translation: https://quran.com/7/31 : O children of Adam, take your adornment at every masjid, and eat and drink, but be not excessive. Indeed, He likes not those who commit excess. ; see also http://corpus.quran.com/qurandictionary.jsp?q=srf ; this is not answer, but material for somebody to use in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Prophet of Islam (PBUH): من اقتصد اغناه الله، و من بذر افقره الله
>
> [Source](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=291&hid=870&pid=134477) (arabic)

At first it's a logical result of economy matters. If you wast your life's funds, one day you will find yourself poor!

We can look at it from other view. When Allah give us a gift as our daily food and etc, he wants us to thank him in words and in act. In words we say thank god (which is شُکر in Quran) but how is Shokr in act? to use it in the best way it is created for.
Can you imagine when you give your children a gift and they thank you and are even so happy but they drop it in trash bin? what that would mean to you? did they really thank you by using it in the way you really wanted them ?

It's logical that if we don't thank Allah for what we are granted, one day we would lose them.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. We are not a typical an internet forum. Therefore we expect answers to be well elaborated, see "[how to answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)" for more information. I strongly recommend you to take our 2 min. [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about this site and the stack exchange model.

Comment: @Kilise: Thank you for your guidance. I've had read it via other stackexchange but I read it again with your suggestion.